# WebApi controller throws method not allowed (MVC)

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I am creating `webapi` (`MVC`) for validating the user and i call "`ValidateUser`" (without HttpGet) from jquery, but i got an error "method not allowed". why?

Is it possible to have more than get method in same UserController? (another method for `productdetails`). how to call from `jquery`?

```
public class UserController : ApiController
{
    private VAMDESchedulerDBEntities db = new VAMDESchedulerDBEntities();

      public IHttpActionResult ValidateUser(string username, string userpassword)
      {
        var userlist = DBActivity.GetUserList();
        var userdetails = userlist.FirstOrDefault(x => x.UserName == username);
        if (userdetails == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
        if (userdetails.UserPassword == userpassword)
            return Ok(userdetails);
        else
            return NotFound();
      }
```

index.html

```
<script>
    var uri2 = 'api/user/ValidateUser?username=xxx&userpassword=xxx';

    $(document).ready(function () {
        alert('document ready ' + uri2);

        // Send an AJAX request
        $.getJSON(uri2)
            .done(function (data) {
                alert(data.UserName + '- PWD : ' + data.UserPassword);

            })
        .fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, err) {
            alert('users api fail: ' + err);
        });
    });

</script>
```

Comment: Where exactly does the error get raised ? In JS or in MVC ? and which code line raises the error ?

Comment: try `[HttpGet]` above the line `public IHttpActionResult ValidateUser`

Comment: PhillipH, I got the error at JS and error message is "method not allowed". If i decorate the ValidateUser as [HttpGet] is working fine. my doubt is two different method(ValidateUser & ValidateUser1) with same parameter, which method has to call?                                                                        var uri2 = 'api/user/ValidateUser1?username=xxx&userpassword=yyy';